# CryptBinaryToString isn't supported on Windows 2000. Is there and alternative?

Tags: winapi, base64

The Windows API function `CryptBinaryToString` isn't supported on Windows 2000.

Is there and alternative?

The main use that I need, is to encode/decode BASE64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want BASE64, you can find some very short implementation like [b64.c](http://base64.sourceforge.net/).
If you need more cryptocipher/certificate related stuff, try get openssl for win32.

Answer (score -1):

You could roll your own from the [MSDN description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379887(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Any reason this is downvoted? Just take a look at the function description.

Comment: Not the one to downvote you, but I don't see any useful information in the MSDN description either - what do you want to say? There's no any alternative information.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, MSDN describes what each flag does and most of them are very straightforward - alternate implementations are readily available or easy to roll your own.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant -- this is a rather easy function to implement safely unlike some of the other components of the Crypto API.